# Redirect output of process

Tags: c#, process, cmd

I want to start a cmd file and immediately get the output.

Look at my code. The intruction `process.WaitForExit()` doesn't wait; why not? 
`copyf.cmd` runs fine if I don't start it in hidden mode, because the shown dosbox runs to the end of the cmd.
In hidden mode the cmd is closed, because `process.WaitForExit()` doen't wiat until the cmd is done.

```
public void doSomeThing(   Queue<string> output, // queue for output log
                        Queue<string> error   // queue for error log
                       )  
{
            String com = "some params";

            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = Properties.Settings.Default.pathTo + @"\Make\copyf.cmd";
            startInfo.Arguments = com;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;

            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                String er;
                String outp;

                while (true)
                {
                    outp = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

                    if(outp != null)
                        output.Enqueue("Output :" + outp + "\n");

                    er = process.StandardError.ReadLine();
                    if (er != null)
                        error.Enqueue("Error :" + er + "\n");
                }
            }));

            process.Start();
            thread.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Why do you figure `WaitForExit` doesn't wait for the process to exit?

Comment: I've found `.WaitForExit()` doesn't work cross threaded, instead I believe i used `while(!proc.HasExited)` (figured was more of a comment than an answer)

Comment: well, its not cross threadding. the thread only reads the output/error. "process" is runnig in the same process where process.WaitForExit(9 is called.

Comment: ah sorry I never scrolled down once I saw Thread

Comment: "runs fine if I don't start it in hidden mode" - Are you saying that if you set `process.CreateNoWindow = false` or change the `WindowStyle` then it works as expected?

Comment: @minitech: I think process.WaitForExit() is done if the comandfile which is runnig in process is done.

Comment: @tux007: What I mean is, why do you *think* it didn't wait long enough? What do you expect, and what actually happens?

Comment: @minitech: I do not get enought output. copyfi.cmd should run a few minuets, but it escapes now in a few seconds.

Comment: Won't your loop get stuck on either `StandardOutput.ReadLine()` or `StandardError.ReadLine()` if there stops being any on either of the two?

Comment: @all: I just do some tests.  If I start the copyf.cmd not hidden, I can close the application and thge dosbox is stikk running. So the Problem is now only the behavior of .WatForExit(). It just doen't wait until the cmd has finished.

Comment: the problem is not solved ...

Answer (score 0):

You should start the actual console command processor "cmd.exe" with C switch instead of invoking a .CMD file.

`/C` switch will keep the `cmd.exe` process held until your command file finishes execution. `WaitForExit()` will wait until CMD.exe finishes execution as well. I have used it numerous occasions. For proper operation of WaitForExit it must be called after StandardError.ReadToEnd(); as [described here in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx) Modified version posted below:

```
    string command = string.Format("{0}\\Make\\copyf.cmd {1}", Properties.Settings.Default.pathTo , com);
    int waitTime = 60000; //1 min as example here
    using (var process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = string.Format("/C \"{0}\"", command)
                }
    })
    {
        try
        {
            if (!process.Start())
            {
                //Log some error "Failed to run command";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log some error "Failed to start process command";
        }

        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit(waitTime);
        if (!process.HasExited)
        {
            //Log something "Command: did not finish in time, terminating process"
            try
            {
                process.Kill();
            }
            catch { }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying, waitforexit doesn't work? or the cmd.exe doesn't work?

Comment: Modified version posted, note the call to StandardError.ReadToEnd(), forgot to put that in my first response.